# Oracle err=918, unixUDBC, instantclinet

Tags: database, oracle, unixodbc, rowid, ora-00918

In program executes the query using SQLExecDirect

```
SELECT 
  q.record_id as record_id, 
  s.scenariusz as scenariusz, 
  u.usluga as usluga, 
  u.priorytet as priorytet, 
  q.vip as vip, 
  q.date_added as date_added, 
  q.chat_server_session_id as chat_server_session_id 
FROM 
  queue_webchat_messenger q 
  JOIN usluga u on u.id_uslugi = q.id_uslugi 
  JOIN scenariusz s on s.id_scen = u.id_scen 
WHERE 
  q.id_agent_soft is NULL
  AND q.state = 'KO' 
ORDER by 
  u.priorytet desc, 
  q.id_uslugi, 
  q.vip desc, 
  q.date_added, 
  q.record_id;
```

In DB logs (Oracle) I get error err = 918

```
=====================
PARSE ERROR #139794508205160:len=450 dep=0 uid=178 oct=3 lid=178 tim=16259156390104 err=918
SELECT ROWID,q.record_id as record_id, s.scenariusz as scenariusz, u.usluga as usluga, u.priorytet as priorytet, q.vip as vip, q.date_added as date_added, q.chat_server_session_id as chat_server_session_id FROM queue_webchat_messenger q JOIN usluga u on u.id_uslugi=q.id_uslugi JOIN scenariusz s on s.id_scen=u.id_scen WHERE q.id_agent_soft is null AND q.state=:"SYS_B_0" ORDER by u.priorytet desc, q.id_uslugi, q.vip desc, q.date_added, q.record_id
CLOSE #139794508205160:c=0,e=2,dep=0,type=0,tim=16259156390850
=====================
```

In the DB logs, the ROWID column is added to the query, I suspect that this column is causing an error.
What could cause the ROWID column to be added and what could cause err = 918?

Comment: What sort of cursor are you asking for in your ODBC application?  Most implementations of scrollable cursors require a key which usually means that the driver adds a `rowid` column to the query.

Comment: I set static cursor

`SQLSetStmtAttr(*hstmt_p, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_CURSOR_STATIC, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add a fake ROWID columns:

```
SELECT 
  q.record_id as ROWID,
  q.record_id as record_id, 
  s.scenariusz as scenariusz, 
  u.usluga as usluga, 
  u.priorytet as priorytet, 
  q.vip as vip, 
  q.date_added as date_added, 
  q.chat_server_session_id as chat_server_session_id 
FROM 
  queue_webchat_messenger q 
  JOIN usluga u on u.id_uslugi = q.id_uslugi 
  JOIN scenariusz s on s.id_scen = u.id_scen 
WHERE 
  q.id_agent_soft is NULL
  AND q.state = 'KO' 
ORDER by 
  u.priorytet desc, 
  q.id_uslugi, 
  q.vip desc, 
  q.date_added, 
  q.record_id;
```

Comment: I get for such

`SQL Error [923] [42000]: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: Trace your session to get what exactly your client sent